# VB.net Environment Changes But I Don't See Where

Tags: vb.net

So my code works fine on my system running Windows 7 Ultimate. It runs fine on a laptop running the same. But my servers are either Windows server OS's or in one case Windows 7 Professional.

Now part of my code reads data from a website. But this data may or may not be there. I have a browser control reading it and I use StringSplit to break it down. If certain parts are there great. If not I let a catch set it to 0.

So the start bit:

```
Dim parts As String() = webdata.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine},
                                             StringSplitOptions.None)
```

I had assumed this is where the problem was. Enviroment.NewLine could be different even under the slightly different Windows 7 server. So I ran a loop on both to dump the data.

```
Dim testloop As Integer = 0
                    Do Until testloop = 25
                        MsgBox(testloop & ") " & parts(testloop))
                        testloop = testloop + 1
                    Loop
```

They both return exactly the same results in exactly the same order. So unless I'm missing something it can't be an environment change there.

But this reads fine on my Windows systems just not the VPS:

```
Try
Firstdata = Parts(22)
Seconddata = Parts(24)
Catch
Firstdata = 0
Seconddata = 0
End Try
```

This might not be the neatest way to do it but it works consistently outside of the VPS and I can't see why an environment would change that.

Looking at the exact same data at the exact same time locally it looks at the table returning the data when it's there and 0's otherwise. On the VPS it just returns 0's.

I thought this would be a simple change to the stringsplit but the loop shows (22) and (24) as the data I'm looking for in the loop. I don't see why the TRY would be different in a different environment.

Any help here would be much appreciated. I can set up a 7 Ultimate server but I'd rather understand what the heck is going on.

Comment: I doubt it's an [`Environment.NewLine`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,1169) issue if its all Windows machines. (And also, the "Unix" version would still work to perform splits but would just leave extra `\r`s in the resultant strings)

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem actually is?  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Locally it runs fine. Returns data when there's data and 0's when there's none. On any of the virtual servers it returns 0's no matter what. Even when the loop is reading them out in the same order.

Comment: You shouldn't use exception handling to control program flow. Maybe there's another error different from "that data isn't here". Put *at least* a messagebox with the `Exception.ToString` or remove the `catch` to see what the actual problem is.